# Detecting patters with str_detect

Tags: r, text

I have some Tweets and I want to detect the number emoticons in there. For this task, I want to use the `hash_emoticons` lexicon of the `textclean` package.

```
hash_emoticons[1:5]
       x                 y
1:   #-) partied all night
2:    %)             drunk
3:   %-)             drunk
4: ',:-l        scepticism
5: ',:-|        scepticism
```

If I use it with the standard function I get this error:

```
library(stringr)

str_detect(Tweets$text, hash_emoticons$x)


longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthError in 
stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)): 
Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)
```

Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please include (a part of) `Tweets` via `dput` in your question and provide a corresponding exact expected outcome.

Comment: I don't think you can call str_detect on a vector of strings and a vector of patterns at the same time. You need to str_detect(Tweets$text, hash_emoticons$x[i]) for each emoticon, or you could paste all the emoticons together and see if the string matches any of them, with e.g. `all_emots <- paste(emoticons$x, collapse = |)`, and then `str_detect(Tweets$text, all_emots)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it using the `stringi` package directly. However, there are some boundary considerations that you need to explain/consider more closely

```
# Generate some data
xxx <- tibble(Text = c("asdasd", ":o)", "hej :o) :o) :-*"))
```

You want to count the number of emoticons that are used in each string so you need to consider the string detect for each emoticon. `str_detect()` will return the presence of any emoticons but not the numbers so we use `stri_count_fixed()` instead.

For example

```
library("stringi")
library("textclean")
# Run through each emoticon
# see if it matches each tweet
# Compute the number of hits
rowSums(sapply(lexicon::hash_emoticons$x, function(i) {
    stringi::stri_count_fixed(xxx$Text, pattern=i)
}))
```

which returns

```
[1] 0 2 5
```

Now if you look at the input string then you'll see 4 emoticons. The element `:o)` will match the two emoticons `:o` and `:o)` which is why the second element is 2. Conversely, the string `hej :o) :o) :-*` will return 5 which is because it matches `:o` twice, `:o)` twice and `:-*` once.